# Problem with spacing after anchor tag in IE6 and IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, anchor, spacing

I'm having problems with my links in IE6 and IE7 (they're working fine in IE8). The HTML is correct and there are no unecessary spaces, but IE isn't removing the space between the end of the linked text - it's running straight on into the continuing paragraph text.

I've searched endlessly, but can't find a solution for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the source code for one of your links?

Comment: a, 
.art-post li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2C9325;
}

a:link,
.art-post li a:link
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2C9325;
}

a:visited, a.visited,
.art-post li a:visited, .art-post li a.visited
{
  color: #2C9325;
}

a:hover, a.hover,
.art-post li a:hover, .art-post li a.hover
{
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #2C9325;
}

Comment: The html on the link is: <p>Consultations and treatments can be carried out in the comfort of your own home or at a local clinic. To request a consultation email <a href="mailto:enquiries@websitedomain">enquiries@website domain</a> or call.</p>

Comment: You need to make a reproducible demo and stick it on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 0):

That is a strange. As soon as an anchor has href that begins with "mailto:" the space between the anchor and the text next to it is removed.

With mootools here is how I fixed the problem :

```
if (Browser.ie6 || Browser.ie7){$$('a[href^=mailto:]').setStyle("margin-right", "0.3em");}
```